# brace in cases environment being displayed incorrectly because of package yhmath

Tags: incompatibility, delimiters, cases, yhmath

Could someone please explain why I get this when using a cases environment?
[image: Broken cases brace]

The code behind this is

```
$$
\underbrace{\mathrm{u}(\tau )}_{\substack{=1\\ \text{για}\ \tau >0}} \underbrace{\mathrm{u}(t-\tau )}_{\substack{=1\\ \text{για}\ \tau <t}} =
  \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{για} \ 0<\tau <t, \ t>0 \\
    &  \\
    0 & \text{αλλού}
  \end{cases}
$$
```

After following some advice in the comments, I have come to the conclusion that this only happens when including package yhmath.
In particular, the offending command in that package is:
\DeclareSymbolFont{largesymbols}{OMX}{yhex}{m}{n}

Now, given that I've been including this package in most of the books I have written, and have no quick way of finding which of the package's commands I have been using, is there some workaround?

Comment: It's because of your use of `$$`... see [Why is `\[` …`\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy) Okay, just kidding. Does this occur at all zoom levels? What about using a different viewer?

Comment: hah nice! but you made me notice something, i have to edit my post. btw, I have also tried it on a mac, same result.

Comment: Please _always_ post a complete document not just a fragment. In particular this is completely dependent on the fonts being used, which we can not tell.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry and thanks, your suggestion made me try to make a MWE and that got me removing packages until.. I found the culprit. yhmath package. :) (Shall I still include a complete document and edit the question? )

Comment: perhaps, if you think there is a reasonable usage of yhmath that is not working it would be worth editing the question to ask about that.

Comment: The yhfonts package has been updated quite recently (the date in the TeX Live repository is 9 July 2013). In particular, the metric file for yrcmex10 has been modified in order to correct some glitches. What OS and TeX distribution are you using?

Comment: I m using windows 7 and miktex 2.9. I updated my miktex installation, the yhfonts package i had was a 2011 version, now it works fine! many thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Old versions of `yhmath` may suffer from this problem. The entire package has been updated on 2013-07-09, in particular the metric files have been fixed.

Updating the package should solve the problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\underbrace{\mathrm{u}(\tau )}_{\substack{=1\\ \text{για}\ \tau >0}} \underbrace{\mathrm{u}(t-\tau )}_{\substack{=1\\ \text{για}\ \tau <t}} =
  \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{για} \ 0<\tau <t, \ t>0 \\
    &  \\
    0 & \text{αλλού}
  \end{cases}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]